# MvvmCross; How to RaisePropertyChange from another ViewModel

Tags: c#, android, listview, mvvm, mvvmcross

I have a **ShoppingCart listView** with **items** that is **bound** to **ShopingCartViewModel**. When I **click** to an **item** it takes me to the **ItemInfoFragment** which is **bound** to **ItemInfoViewModel**.

In **ItemInfoFragment** I have a **button** which **deletes** the **item** and **removes** it from the **ShoppingCart** **listview**.

**My problem is**; After i **delete** the **item** and **press** **backbutton** to return to my **previously** **activity**, the **ShoppingCart** **listView** still **shows** the **Item** that I **deleted**.

**My Question is;** How to RaisePropertyChange in ShoppingCartViewModel when i exit the ItemInfoFragment?

Comment: Take a look at the [Messenger](https://mvvmcross.com/docs/messenger) plugin as an alternative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have a few options:

**Shared Persistent Storage**

If you use a storage/caching solution like [SQLite](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/data/databases/sqlite/) or [Realm](https://realm.io/docs/xamarin/latest/#getting-started) etc. Which can be used to read and modify the same shopping cart data between pages. You can then use view life cycle events (`OnResume`[Android] or `ViewWillAppear`[iOS]) to retrieve the latest from the cache.

Alternatively if the shopping cart data size is small you could read/write it to [MvvmCross Settings Plugin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Cheesebaron.MvxPlugins.Settings/). You will just have to serialize and deserialize your objects as you can only save basic types like strings, bools, int etc.

**Dependency Injection Shared Instance**

You can create an in memory cache via using a shared class instance the can be shared between multiple ViewModels. This classes properties can bind directly to your various views. Any changes to the list will update all views that bind to it. One thing to note is that you will have to manually handle clean up if you require the memory space occupied by the this instance class.

*Example:*

Example model

```
public class ItemInfo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

Shared class instance and interface

```
public interface ISharedShoppingCart
{
    MvxObservableCollection<ItemInfo> ShoppingCartItems { get; set; }
}

public class SharedShoppingCart : MvxNotifyPropertyChanged, ISharedShoppingCart
{
    MvxObservableCollection<ItemInfo> _shoppingCartItems;
    public MvxObservableCollection<ItemInfo> ShoppingCartItems
    {
        get { return _shoppingCartItems; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _shoppingCartItems, value); }
    }
}
```

Make sure to register the class and interface

```
public class App : MvxApplication
{
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        /* Other registerations*/

        Mvx.LazyConstructAndRegisterSingleton<ISharedShoppingCart, SharedShoppingCart>();
    }
}
```

Example usage in shared ViewModels

```
public class ShopingCartViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    readonly ISharedShoppingCart _sharedShoppingChart;

    public ShopingCartViewModel(ISharedShoppingCart sharedShoppingChart)
    {
        _sharedShoppingChart = sharedShoppingChart;
    }

    public MvxObservableCollection<ItemInfo> ShoppingCartItems
    {
        get { return _sharedShoppingChart.ShoppingCartItems; }
        set { _sharedShoppingChart.ShoppingCartItems = value; }
    }
}

public class ItemInfoViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    readonly ISharedShoppingCart _sharedShoppingCart;

    public ItemInfoViewModel(ISharedShoppingCart sharedShoppingCart)
    {
        _sharedShoppingCart = sharedShoppingCart;
    }

    void RemoveItemFromCart(int id)
    {
        _sharedShoppingCart.ShoppingCartItems
            .Remove(_sharedShoppingCart.ShoppingCartItems.Single(x => x.Id == id));
    }
}
```

**Pub/Sub**

You could send [messages](https://mvvmcross.com/docs/messenger) back to the shopping cart ViewModel using the [MvvmCross Messenger Plugin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmCross.Plugin.Messenger/).