# MvvmCross On back from another ViewModel

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have the following simple navigation flow:

> ViewModel1=>ViewModel2=>ViewModel3

When ViewModel3 is closed, I publish using the Message plugin to ViewModel some information which needs to get added to list in ViewModel1. Unfortunately nothing happens (I raise NotifChanged). In my opinion it happens because it's not called from UI.

What is the best way to achieve a refreshing list? I don't see any method in the ViewModel which is called when ViewModel is back from another ViewModel i.e. when ViewModel3 is closed.

EDIT:
Example Code:

```
   public class WarehouseInViewModel : MvxViewModel
    {
        public WarehouseInViewModel(IMvxMessenger messenger)
        {
            mvxMessenger = messenger;
            myToken = mvxMessenger.Subscribe<mAcceptMessage>(OnMyMessageArrived);

        }

        public override void Start()
        {
            base.Start();

        }


        private readonly IMvxMessenger mvxMessenger;
        private MvxSubscriptionToken myToken;

        private List<mProduct> productItems;
        public List<mProduct> ProductItems
        {
            get { return productItems; }
            set
            {
                productItems = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => ProductItems);
            }
        }
        private MvxCommand<AcceptMenuItem> buttonCommand;
        public ICommand ButtonCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return buttonCommand = buttonCommand ?? new MvxCommand<AcceptMenuItem>(MenuClick);
            }
        }
        private void OnMyMessageArrived(mAcceptMessage myMessage)
        {
            mProduct product = mProduct.GetById(myMessage.ProductId);
    //Something more ...

    // There I want to update my Listview which is binded to ProductItems
            ProductItems.Add(product);

            RaisePropertyChanged(() => ProductItems);
        }
        public async void MenuClick(AcceptMenuItem menu)
        {
            ShowViewModel<WarehouseInScanViewModel>();
        }

    }
```

And the most important method from Third ViewModel (we assume that secont ViewMOdel only opens third, and it's closed properly)):

```
public void ButtonNextClick()
    {
       vxMessenger.Publish(new mAcceptMessage(this, productId, scannedLocation.Id, productQuantity));
                    Close(this);

    }
```

So, when I'm back from third VM, I want to refreash ListView. I can't do it from OnMyMessageArrived because it's not in UI thread.

Comment: Could you provide some example code? Alternatively you can check out this [Stackoverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42441831/mvvmcross-how-to-raisepropertychange-from-another-viewmodel/42447761#answer-42447761) for some other ideas in refreshing data on passed ViewModels.

Comment: @Plac3Hold3r I provided example code. I'm open to other solutions. I thought about simple database to store products, but it seems like a bad solution.

Comment: In short, do you mean you would like to add data from `ViewModel3` to `ViewModel1` when the `ViewModel3` closed?

Comment: @DarrenChristopher Rather on closing. I need to pass some data from ViewModel3 to ViewModel1 and display it on List. I thought that I can achieve this by Messanger plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `GlobalVars.cs` static class (probably create Services folder and put it inside so it will be cleaner) with static fields and use that as the data source of your list in `ViewModel1`. Then, all you need to do is add the data on the `List` in `GlobalVars.cs` from `ViewModel3`.

*Services/GlobalVars.cs*

```
public static class GlobalVars
{
    public static List<CustomClass> aGlobalVariable;
}
```

*ViewModel1.cs*

```
using Services;
...
public CustomClass LocalVariable
{
    get { return GlobalVars.aGlobalVariable; }
    set 
    {
        GlobalVars.aGlobalVariable = value;
        ...
    }
}

//refresh purpose
public void refresh()
{
    RaisePropertyChanged(() => LocalVariable);
}
```

*ViewModel3.cs*

```
//just add the GlobalVars List when you need it
GlobalVars.aGlobalVariable.Add(new CustomClass());
```

To refresh your `ListView`, when you get back to the `ViewModel1`, you just simply call `refresh()` method from the activity. Below is how you access `ViewModel` in activity.

*View1.cs*

```
ViewModel1 vm;
...
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    ...
    vm = ViewModel as ViewModel1;
    ...
}
//what you want to do is refreshing the list on resume
protected override void OnResume()
{
    base.OnResume()
    vm.refresh();
    ... //other things you might want to do
}
```

Hope this answer could help.

Answer (score 0):

To make it work you should either change your ***List ProductItems*** to ***ObservableColletion*** or do this

```
ProductItems.Add(product);
ProductItems = ProductItems.ToList();
```